# How To Enable Proguard with react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to reduce my APK Size 
I followed these https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android
and run ./gradlew bundleRelease instead of assembleRelease 
But I Got Error

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   Job failed,

So how can I solve it, I'm Google it but the issue is still! 
But without Enable Proguard it's work very well and I got (Aab & .Apk )  SO How To Solve it!

I think the issue with this file but I don't know how to configure that!

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "APP_NAME",
  "version": "1.12.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "@turf/distance": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.1.4",
    "@turf/invariant": "^6.1.2",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.3.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/parser": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-devtools": "^3.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want Proguard Enabled (minifyEnabled true in android/app/build.gradle) while using "react-native-firebase" package in your app, you need to update your proguard rules.

in (android/app/proguard-rules.pro)
add the following lines:

```
-keep class io.invertase.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.**
```

for more information you can check https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android just before Step 4.

If it doesn't work out, you must go to documentations of the other packages you use and lookup for additional preferences must be done in order to make their settings compatible with Proguard enabled.

Comment: Update: it seems the rnfirebase v6 doesn't need rules anymore. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3770#issuecomment-642232318